# Can we use different tense verbs after an "and"?

Tags: tense

If I say

> They won and pass the title to the successor.

Will it be correct?

Comment: Can you please give us more information on what you're trying to say? This sentence doesn't make much sense to me. What is the context?

Comment: I vote 'no' in this case; it should be: _They won and passed the title to the successor_. There may be times when this sort of thing would be acceptable, but I can't think of a good example off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your title question is *yes*, in some circumstances. But for your specific example, *no*, that does not work. Think about when these actions are occurring -

If they won some time ago, and are currently passing on the title (maybe it takes a while to transfer for some reason?), you should not use simple present tense - [it is not used to express events happening now](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/). Instead, use present progressive tense to indicate actions in progress:

> They won and **are passing** the title to the successor.

Or perhaps they won in the past, and the rule is that they have to pass on the title, but there is no successor yet. In that case, future tense is valid:

> They won and **will pass** the title to the successor.

Or the simplest case, they won in the past, and have since passed on the title:

> They won and **passed** the title to the successor.

[Purdue OWL's page on Verb Tense Consistency](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/601/04/) has some more examples of how and when to shift verb tense.